# Kernel: Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 31 on CPU 3

Tags: debian, kernel

I'm receiving this error on "Linux Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.46-1+deb7u1 x86_64":

```
Message from syslogd@hostname at Feb 14 02:54:51 ...
kernel:[81927.464687] Uhhuh. NMI received for unknown reason 31 on CPU 3.

Message from syslogd@hostname at Feb 14 02:54:51 ...
kernel:[81927.464743] Do you have a strange power saving mode enabled?

Message from syslogd@hostname at Feb 14 02:54:51 ...
kernel:[81927.464791] Dazed and confused, but trying to continue
```

After I receive this, the server just reboots.

I read on some other websites that it's related to CPU hangout? But they were not helpful resources.

Answer (score 7):

This is almost always bad hardware. Run memtest for a couple of hours since that's the easiest thing to do. From there investigate your processor, add-in cards, motherboard, etc.

Comment: Do you have any other tools that I could run under the kernel? Since this is server machine that's not on any near of me..

Comment: Bad interrupts usually means "bad southbridge chipset".

Comment: This just happened to me, all my terminal windows received those messages, but nothing bad happened and it hasn't happened again. Should I be worried?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above this seems to be hardware error,"NMI received for unknown reason 31 on CPU 3".NMI or non maskable interrupt is a hardware interrupt that processor can't ignore.NMI interrupt is usually for important task or to report hardware error

OS doesn't have much role to play,so here you can do these things

1. Install mcelog rpm to get more deeper info
2. If its a HP node,Change the HP BIOS option for the power saving mode to "OS Control" from any other mode configured such as "Dynamic Power Saving Mode" or "Static - High Performance" mode.
3. Upgrade BIOS or firmware

But the best advice is to contact hardware vendor